# Custom cancel button on multiple choice dialog in preferencesfragment

Tags: localization, dialog, preferences

I'm using PreferencesFragment with addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) as described on Android Development site. And it works great and is a simple way of making multiple choice pref...but, my app is to be localized for Serbia and it has to support Cyrillic and Latin.

Now title and choices are easy to customize for Latin in res/values and Cyrillic in res/values-sr...

The problem is "cancel" at bottom of the dialog...
res/values is for default and that's English and when dialog pops everything is in Serbian Latin except cancel.

The second problem is on some phones Serbian language is supported in Latin (normally it's Cyrillic like on Nexus 4, 7, etc.) so everything in res/values-sr comes up in Latin so I'm using res/values-ru which works everywhere, but again the same problem with "cancel"...it's now in Russian.

Is there a simple way to customize "cancel" or to remove it?

Comment: maybe you can programmatically modify it with Java, there are dozens of questions and answers on programmatically modifying controls.